# jquery mobile 1.4.1 panel transition on close

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, ios7, jquery-mobile-panel

I upgraded to jquery mobile 1.4.1 from 1.3.2. In the old version, the panel used to open and close with a transition. Now it only opens with a transition. I'm pretty sure this is because of the new version because the documentation even shows it closing abruptly:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/panel/

How can I make it close with a transition instead of abruptly? I tried adding

```
.ui-panel-animate {
    transition: transform 1350ms ease 0s !important;
}
```

(I found it from another stackoverflow answer) but it doesn't seem to do anything. If you look at the link above it shows the panel closing abruptly. Here is how I want it to close like:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/panels/

Comment: In 1.4 there was an issue with panels and pages with no transitions. I guess but not sure, they removed closing animation to fix that bug. If you check 1.4 panels close with animation.

Comment: please show more code

Comment: I just ran into this bug. It doesn't occur on jQM 1.4 only in jQM 1.4.1.